# Secure open source Android email client app

Tags: android, email

I am having continues problems with gmail app so I need an alternative. What app has good features specially in security and also open source ?

Comment: I am testing now fairemail and boomerang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from [K-9 Mail](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.fsck.k9/) already recommended in another answer, you might wish to take a look at **[FairEmail](https://f-droid.org/packages/eu.faircode.email/)** which some prefer over K-9. It is open-source as well (find its source [at Github](https://github.com/M66B/open-source-email)) and actively developed. I'm not using it myself, but heard from many people using it about its clear interface, good feature-set, and reliability. Some claim it's more intuitive, but that's also something currently worked on with K-9 while moving it on to its rebrand. Some screenshots for you to compare (left: K-9, right: FairEmail):

[image] [image]
<sup>Menus</sup>

[image] [image]
<sup>Compose a mail</sup>

Next to F-Droid (the link above), FairEmail is also available [at PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.email) if you insist. I always recommend using F-Droid as source for your apps, but I might be biased; though if you prefer libre open source apps, that's the place to go for them.

Comment: Thanks. So the advantages of F-Droid that it has all as open source ?

Comment: I am using now FairEmail it is the only good option other apps has some problems.

Comment: There're more advantages, like transparency. Proprietary components (such as Crashlytics) are not allowed, so most trackers etc. cannot be part of any app there. And if there's anything you'd better know before, there are Anti-Features making that clear (e.g. something depending on a proprietary framework like GMS being present, or connecting to a non-free network, etc). I wrote an article series on that if you want to "dive in deeper": [F-Droid: The privacy-friendly alternative to Google Play Store](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/fdroid-intro-1)

Answer (score 1):

https://k9mail.app/

It's a very good email client. As far as I understand the project is in the process of joining Mozilla Foundation and to be rebranded as Thunderbird for Android.

I have been using this for about a year now and I am happy user. :)

Comment: I can second this suggestion, using the app for about 10 years. Speaking of open source, you can get K-9/Thunderbird [from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.fsck.k9/) (where the open-source apps live) as well as from [PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) (where you need to be careful what apps you pick ;) – @linasj you might wish to include these links directly with your answer to make them easier to spot, +1 meanwhile).

Comment: Thanks but K9 does not sync also no notification although I gave it all permissions

Comment: Funny. K-9 does that fine for me. But it might depend on the provider to a degree.